# Startup Topaz issue

Tags: boot

So, I was am using an ubuntu 20.04 since last 2 months since I switched from Windows. I was using my laptop casually and I started getting some browser issues while running it. I restarted it and there were some errors - sort of sda2 error. I tried to clean it following an article but i messed it up more I think. Please I need help, I don't understand what error is exactly or how to go around it. I can access bios and ubuntu recovery options but they are not helping much. Image of error is attached. Please help.

I can't attach image due to less reputation. Errors i am getting are /dev/sda2 clean. files blocks.
cannott open /etc/matchine-id: No such file or director
Failed create system users
driver pcspkr is already registered
Topaz not supported in kfd

The startup is freezed basically and this is the error. Please help.